# setTimeout not working, and yes the function does not have ()

Tags: javascript

I am making a timer and for some reason the timer is not properly decrementing using the `countDown` function in the code below. I am using `setTimeout` to call it `countDown` repeatedly but when I checked the debugger JavaScript does not even go to that line, after the second-to-last line `timeEl.textContent = tempMinutes + ":" + tempSeconds;` it just stops. I tried `setInterval` but its the same.
I want to know how to have the timer go down and `setTimeout` to do its thing, but how? Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

```js
const workBtnEl = document.querySelector("#work-btn");
const shortBreakBtnEl = document.querySelector("#short-break-btn");
const longBreakBtnEl = document.querySelector("#long-break-btn");
let timeEl = document.querySelector("#time");

const work = 25; 
const shortBreak = 5;
const longBreak = 15;

let currentMinutes, currentSeconds = 0;

workBtnEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
    timeEl.textContent = "25:00";
    currentMinutes = work;
    countDown(currentMinutes, 0);
});

function countDown(minutes, seconds) {
    if (seconds == 0) {
        if (minutes == 0) {
            return;
        }
        minutes -= 1;
        seconds = 59;
    }

    let tempSeconds = seconds;
    let tempMinutes = minutes;

    if (seconds < 10) {
        tempSeconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        tempMinutes = "0" + minutes
    }

    timeEl.textContent = tempMinutes + ":" + tempSeconds;

    let time = setTimeout(countDown, 1000, minutes, seconds);
}
```

```html
<button id="work-btn">
  Work
</button>
<button id="short-break-btn">
  Short break
</button>
<button id="long-break-btn">
  Long break
</button>

<span id="time">Time</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never decrease `seconds` when it is non-zero.

So add that after the `if` block:

```
if (seconds == 0) {
   // your code...
} else seconds--;    // <---
```

Comment: Actually, a better way is to pass `seconds - 1` in the recursive `setTimeout`. So the first display of the countdown shows `:00`.

Comment: This fixes the issue, but this won't be particularly accurate timer. If visibility of the page changes, the timer events stop running. Better to calculate the elapsed time each time the countDown runs, so you can handle switching tabs

Comment: There are a lot of comments to make; but the question is about why the count down got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the seconds variable in the `countDown` function otherwise the same text will be printed to your text area each time.

Right now you just have a condition if the seconds are 0 then set seconds to 59.

Answer (score 0):

See what you have done in this line :

```
let currentMinutes, currentSeconds = 0;
```

currentMinutes will be undefined mostly, I used Node REPL to check
If you have something like :

```
let a, b = 0
```

The value of a was undefined & b got set to zero
An appropriate assignment would be

```
let currentMinutes = 0;
let currentSeconds = 0;
```